# Error Python pandas: time data '20160101-000000' does not match format '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing

I've searched SO and questions I've found do not seem to cover my case. I've followed code from https://gist.github.com/gjreda/7433f5f70299610d9b6b using directives from https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior and wrote in Jupyter Python notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS')
pd1 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\am\shared-2\topandas.txt',sep=':',header=None, names  = ['a','b','c','d'], parse_dates=[1], converters={'a': to_datetime}, index_col = 'a')
#pd2 = pd1.to_datetime (pd1.)
pd1
```

I've got error

> ValueError: time data '20160101-000000' does not match format
>   '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS'

I'm looking into expression and do not see where I made mistake.

Full error below:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 from datetime import datetime
>         2 to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS')
>   ----> 3 pd1 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\am\shared-2\topandas.txt',sep=':',header=None, names 
>   = ['a','b','c','d'], parse_dates=[1], converters={'a': to_datetime})
>         4 #pd2 = pd1.to_datetime (pd1.)
>         5 pd1
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar,
>   comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       701 
>   --> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       703 
>       704     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       433 
>       434     try:
>   --> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       436     finally:
>       437         parser.close()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1137     def read(self, nrows=None):    1138
>   nrows = _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
>   -> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1140     1141         # May alter columns / col_dict
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1993     def read(self, nrows=None):    1994
>   try:
>   -> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1996         except StopIteration:    1997             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._apply_converter()
>
> in (d)
>         1 from datetime import datetime
>   ----> 2 to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS')
>         3 pd1 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\am\shared-2\topandas.txt',sep=':',header=None, names 
>   = ['a','b','c','d'], parse_dates=[1], converters={'a': to_datetime})
>         4 #pd2 = pd1.to_datetime (pd1.)
>         5 pd1
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls,
>   data_string, format)
>       575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
>       576     format string."""
>   --> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>       578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
>       579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string,
>   format)
>       357     if not found:
>       358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
>   --> 359                          (data_string, format))
>       360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
>       361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
>
> ValueError: time data '20160101-000000' does not match format
>   '%YYYY%mm%dd-%HH%MM%SS'

Comment: I do not see `%YYYY` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is necessary to change format to use only one letter, also check [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/):

```
to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

Another similar solution:

```
to_datetime = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, format='%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

Comment: thanx, been long since I used python :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that `%Y` matches a 4-digit year - so by giving `%YYYY` you're actually matching "*4-digit year, followed by three Ys*". This holds for the others too.

Try the following format string instead: `%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

Comment: thanx, been long since I used python :-)